# Javascript/html5 selector

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do the HTML5 fundamentals tutorial and this is so far my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>HTML Fundamentals</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="result" class="well"
        <div id="log">&nbsp;</div>
        <hr />
        <div class="item" id="div1">div 1</div>
        <div class="item" id="div2">div 2</div>
        <div class="item" id="div3">div 3</div>
        <div class="item" id="div4">div 4</div>
        <div class="item" id="div5">div 5</div>
        <div class="item" id="div6">div 6</div>
        <hr />
   </div>
```

```
function initiate() {

    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    var log = document.querySelector('#log');
    log.innerText = 'There are' + divs.length + 'DIVs on this page';

}

addEventListener("load", initiate);
```

But it does not show the message as i would like. Care to point out what i'm missing?

Comment: `<div id="result" class="well"` should have `>` at the end for starters: `<div id="result" class="well">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid: You're missing a `>` on `<div id="result" class="well"`.

Once you fix these you get an accurate result: [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zgLVC/). (6 `.item` `div` elements, 1 `#log` `div` element and 1 `.well` `div` element = 8 total).

Comment: 1 and 2 have no effect on markup validity, although to be fair the OP does seem to be trying to adhere to XHTML syntax by self-closing their void elements, in which case all start and end tags for `html`, `head` and `body` should be included.

Comment: @BoltClock well I never knew that! How interesting. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an end of tag character

```
 <div id="result" class="well"
```

should be:

```
 <div id="result" class="well">
```

otherwise it seems to work fine.
Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/B3b3N/